# テンプレートファイルで同じプロジェクト内のクラスを呼び出す

Tags: c#

テンプレートファイルでプロジェクトの名前空間の中にあるクラスを呼び出そうとすると
エラー「変換をコンパイルしています: 型または名前空間の名前 'WindowsFormsApp1' が見つかりませんでした (using ディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が指定されていることを確認してください)。」が発生します。
どうすればよいのでしょうか。

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="WindowsFormsApp1" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>

<#
    string strText = WindowsFormsApp1.Common.GetVersionData();
#>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ビルド前にコード生成されるため、同じプロジェクト内のクラスはまだ存在しておらず、したがって呼び出すことはできません。

Comment: 別のプロジェクトにクラスを移動して呼び出せば可能でしょうか。

Comment: @user30138 可能ではありますが、そもそもの問題として当該メソッドは実行時に使用されるのでしょうか？ コンパイル時のみに使用されるのであれば、T4に含めてしまった方が適切かと思います。

Comment: 他のプロジェクトで使用する可能性が出てきたので該当メソッドの入ったプロジェクトをdllにすることにしました。現質問と変わってしまうため、改めて質問を起こします。